# i want to ascending or decending order by date from csv file to php

Tags: php, csv, sorting

```
<?php
    // Create a table from a csv file 

    function jj_readcsv($filename, $header=false) {
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        echo '<table id="basic-datatables" class="display table table-striped table-hover"><thead class="text-capitalize">';
        //display header row if true
        if ($header) {
            $csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle);
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($csvcontents as $headercolumn) {
                echo "<th>$headercolumn</th>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
        </thead>
        <?php
        // displaying contents
        while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($csvcontents as $column ) {
                echo "<td>$column</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        fclose($handle);
        }
    jj_readcsv('../upload/historyorders.csv',true);
?>
```

This is the code i am using to display the csv contents to php, but i am unable to sort by date in ascending or decending order, can someone help me out

Comment: That will not work correctly as a function - you have raw HTML in that function - any HTML should be printed not left as raw html. Perhaps adding some of the actual CSV data would help?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the syntax should not be a problem here, as far as I can see? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php (Whether it makes much _sense_ to use this for just one single closing HTML tag, whereas other single tags still get output via echo, would be a different question ...)

Comment: @CBroe - I would have thought that having `</thead>` in the body of that function would cause an issue - turns out I was mistaken - when I tested it seemed fine but still a peculiar approach